# how to replace get_template_part('loop','tag') with explicit styled version?

Tags: loop, tags, get-template-part

So my theme has a tag.php, that contains this line:

`get_template_part('loop','tag');`

that runs the loop and spits out the tag entries.  I'm modifying it to include post thumbnails (using if(has_post_thumbnail()) { the_post_thumbnail() }), but have run into a need to add more styling.  to do this I need to get access to the code that `get_template_part()` is spitting out.

i know i should be able to do this somehow by creating my own loop in loop-tag.php or some such thing, but can't find an example.  can someone give me a simple example of a loop-tag.php that would break the functions of `get_template_part('loop','tag')` into it's components?

Comment: what components are you talking about? have you tried to save a copy of loop.php as loop-tag.php, which should give you the same output as you have now, but which you can then start to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the purpose of [`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part). It is a wrapper for [`locate_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template), which itself is just a wrapper for `include()`.

By calling `get_template_part( 'loop', 'tag' )`, you are telling WordPress to look for/include a file based on the following priority:

1. Child Theme `loop-tag.php`
2. Parent Theme `loop-tag.php`
3. Child Theme `loop.php`
4. Parent Theme `loop.php`

**If you need to modify the markup of the loop itself, then you simply need to modify the appropriate file, according to the above priority list - e.g. `loop-tag.php` in your Theme or Child Theme.**

You may need to *create* this file; if so, copy `loop.php`, name the copy `loop-tag.php`, and edit as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The *easiest* way to do this is find your loop, in your case it looks like it would be in a file called `loop.php`.

1. Make a backup copy of tag.php
2. Delete `get_template_part('loop','tag');` from tag.php
3. Copy/Paste the contents of loop.php into tag.php
4. Hit refresh

Now you can style tag.php however you want.

Note: If there is a problem make sure you did not remove the header and footer calls, or any other markup from tag.php (or loop.php), next time pastebin your whole tag.php code.